# Configuring perl to be more strict with file IO errors

Tags: perl

I have a perl script with a line similar to the following

```
my $in = new IO::File ($fn)
    or warn "Sorry, there was a problem opening $fn: $!\n",
    and return;
```

On my system if the file path specified by `$fn` does not exist, it displays the warning and returns from the function.

One some systems, however, it is printing the standard `could not open {file path}: No such file or directory` and quitting the script instead of printing the warning I suppied and returning.

I have changed the code to be more defensive, checking if the file exists before opening it. It would be useful to know, however, why this difference occurred so that I can properly test my code in future without having to release and await bug reports.

Is there some configuration for perl which makes it more strict when errors such as files not existing occur?

Comment: I don't suppose someone snuck in a `use Acme::use::strict::with::pride;` into some other file while you weren't looking, did they? :)

Comment: That doesn't look syntactically valid.  Is there some reason you aren't using clearer syntax, like: `unless (my  $input_handle = IO::File->new($filename)) { warn "couldn't IO::File->new($filename): $!"; return; }`?  Plus why aren't you just calling `open` instead of bouncing through all the module gunk?

Answer (score 2):

Since it's not printing your warning, it must be `die`-ing earlier. Perl does not normally die with IO errors, unless you use a module like [`Fatal`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Fatal) (now deprecated as an interface) or [`autodie`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autodie) (the preferred interface).

So, you can look for inclusion of `autodie` or `Fatal` modules as well in the current runtime:

```
say "Fatal included from : $INC{'Fatal.pm'}";
```

Note: the preferred `autodie` includes `Fatal`, so one check for either of them.

Of course, one of the more complete ways of finding out what it is doing is to use

```
perl -d /path/to/io_script_dying_on_me.pl
```

and step through the IO::File::new call--however, *some Perl modules act different when the debugger is detected*.

---

If it had printed your message, somebody might have overridden the warn that `warn` to die on warnings. They could do this by changing the warning handler (`$SIG{__WARN__}`), or by installing a different definition into the `CORE::GLOBAL` namespace. the You can check this out with the following:

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Deparse = 1;

say Data::Dumper->Dump( [ $SIG{__WARN__} ], [ '$SIG{__WARN__}' ] );
say Data::Dumper->Dump( [ \&CORE::GLOBAL::warn ], [ '*CORE::GLOBAL::warn' ] );
```

Comment: Actually it's not printing the warning I specified. I've edited the post to make that clearer.